# JPA 2.0, Criteria API, Subqueries, In in Subquery

Tags: jpa, subquery, criteria

I have tried to write a query statement with a subquery and an IN expression for many times. But I have never succeeded.

I always get not right result after building query in JPA. My SQL request below:

```
SELECT distinct 
  ss.*
FROM
  table1 ss  
where 
  ss.active=1 
and 
  ss.id not in (select ia.organization_id from table2 ia where ia.is_allow = 'Y')
```

My code using Criteria API below :

```
CriteriaQuery<Table1> cq = qb.createQuery(Table1.class);
Root<Table1> table = cq.from(Table1.class);
cq.select(table);
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

Subquery<Table1> subquery = cq.subquery(Table1.class);
Root<Table2> subroot = subquery.from(Table2.class);
subquery.select(subroot.get(Table2_.table1));
subquery.where(qb.equal(subroot.get(Table2_.isAllow.getName()), Boolean.TRUE));

predicateList.add(qb.not(qb.in(table.get(Table1_.id.getName())).value(subquery)));
if (!predicateList.isEmpty()) {
            Predicate[] array = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
            cq.where(qb.and(predicateList.toArray(array)));
} 
cq.distinct(true);
TypedQuery<Table1> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
return qry.getResultList();
```

After this i get follow sql request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.*

FROM TABLE1 t0
WHERE (t0.ACTIVE = 1 AND NOT (t0.ID IN (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 t2, TABLE1 t1 WHERE ((t2.IS_ALLOW = 'Y')
AND (t1.ID = t2.ORGANIZATION_ID)))))
```

Why in this code "SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 t2, TABLE1 t1" and etc.... I wait in this t1.id.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If Subquery returns just and integer

```
select ia.organization_id from table2 ia where ia.is_allow = 'Y'
```

try this.

```
Subquery<Integer> subquery = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Table2> subroot = subquery.from(Table2.class);
subquery.select(subroot.get("organization_id"));
subquery.where(qb.equal(subroot.get("is_allow"), Boolean.TRUE));
```

Subquery above should return the integers that will be placed in the IN statement.

Then your logic could apply.

```
CriteriaQuery<Table1> cq = qb.createQuery(Table1.class);
Root<Table1> table = cq.from(Table1.class);
cq.select(table);
cq.distinct(true)
   .where(qb.not(qb.in(root.get("get")).value(subquery))
   .and(cb<Integer>equals(root.get("active"),1))
```

Not sure if this will work.
TypedQuery qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
If cq "Criteria Query" is type of Table1.class, then the TypedQuery will be 
Change to

```
TypedQuery<Table1> qry = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
```